# PHP JSON array issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have tryed almost everything to get the data in **observations** in a foreach sentence in php but can get it to output any data.

I Want to get the observations rows listed so i can insert it into a MySQL DB

```
{
"version":"2.0","secret":"meraki","type":"DevicesSeen","data":{
    "apMac":"88:15:44:84:4c:90","apFloors":[],"apTags":["","recently-added",""]
    ,"observations":[{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":0.2907945825483442,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:24:43Z","ssid":null,"os":"Cisco/Linksys Router","clientMac":"94:9f:3e:06:c1:6c","seenEpoch":1495283083,"rssi":47,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":"/10.226.198.65","location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":5.374873752610671,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:30Z","ssid":"DanfossConnect","os":"Slingbox","clientMac":"00:11:f6:f3:43:06","seenEpoch":1495283130,"rssi":46,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Asia Pacific Microsystems"},{
        "ipv4":"/172.16.0.25","location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":33.788906850703945,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:29Z","ssid":"Wireless WiFi","os":"HP Printer","clientMac":"c4:34:6b:08:dc:6d","seenEpoch":1495283129,"rssi":13,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hewlett-Packard"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":14.90854452921782,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:24:45Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"54:60:09:0e:08:d2","seenEpoch":1495283085,"rssi":31,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Google"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":0.287722117087862,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:54Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"94:9f:3e:06:c1:6d","seenEpoch":1495283154,"rssi":46,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":4.189862222398972,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:49Z","ssid":null,"os":"Cisco/Linksys Router","clientMac":"5c:aa:fd:40:29:78","seenEpoch":1495283149,"rssi":41,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":38.279358673491906,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:23:18Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"f4:42:8f:c3:84:8b","seenEpoch":1495282998,"rssi":16,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Samsung"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":39.49058481097055,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:28Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"a0:8c:fd:06:ec:17","seenEpoch":1495283128,"rssi":9,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hewlett-Packard"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":4.966494178173178,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:49Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"5c:aa:fd:40:29:79","seenEpoch":1495283149,"rssi":40,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46452206894476,"lng":9.39005605565066,"unc":28.907921961158962,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:22Z","ssid":null,"os":"iOS","clientMac":"b0:70:2d:84:38:cf","seenEpoch":1495283122,"rssi":13,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Apple"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":40.978157267912586,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:34Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"60:6d:c7:85:91:17","seenEpoch":1495283134,"rssi":20,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hon Hai/Foxconn"}
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$something = json_decode('{
"version":"2.0",
"secret":"meraki",
"type":"DevicesSeen",
"data":{
    "apMac":"88:15:44:84:4c:90",
    "apFloors":[],
    "apTags":["","recently-added",""],
    "observations":[{
        "ipv4":null,
        "location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":0.2907945825483442,"x":[],"y":[]},
        "seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:24:43Z",
        "ssid":null,
        "os":"Cisco/Linksys Router",
        "clientMac":"94:9f:3e:06:c1:6c",
        "seenEpoch":1495283083,
        "rssi":47,
        "ipv6":null,
        "manufacturer":"Sonos"
    },{
        "ipv4":"/10.226.198.65","location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":5.374873752610671,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:30Z","ssid":"DanfossConnect","os":"Slingbox","clientMac":"00:11:f6:f3:43:06","seenEpoch":1495283130,"rssi":46,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Asia Pacific Microsystems"},{
        "ipv4":"/172.16.0.25","location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":33.788906850703945,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:29Z","ssid":"Wireless WiFi","os":"HP Printer","clientMac":"c4:34:6b:08:dc:6d","seenEpoch":1495283129,"rssi":13,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hewlett-Packard"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":14.90854452921782,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:24:45Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"54:60:09:0e:08:d2","seenEpoch":1495283085,"rssi":31,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Google"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":0.287722117087862,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:54Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"94:9f:3e:06:c1:6d","seenEpoch":1495283154,"rssi":46,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":4.189862222398972,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:49Z","ssid":null,"os":"Cisco/Linksys Router","clientMac":"5c:aa:fd:40:29:78","seenEpoch":1495283149,"rssi":41,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":38.279358673491906,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:23:18Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"f4:42:8f:c3:84:8b","seenEpoch":1495282998,"rssi":16,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Samsung"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":39.49058481097055,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:28Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"a0:8c:fd:06:ec:17","seenEpoch":1495283128,"rssi":9,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hewlett-Packard"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":4.966494178173178,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:49Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"5c:aa:fd:40:29:79","seenEpoch":1495283149,"rssi":40,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46452206894476,"lng":9.39005605565066,"unc":28.907921961158962,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:22Z","ssid":null,"os":"iOS","clientMac":"b0:70:2d:84:38:cf","seenEpoch":1495283122,"rssi":13,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Apple"},{
        "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":40.978157267912586,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:34Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"60:6d:c7:85:91:17","seenEpoch":1495283134,"rssi":20,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hon Hai/Foxconn"}]
  }
}');

foreach($something->data->observations[0] as $key => $val){
  if($key === "location"){
    echo '<hr><h4>here is the location object</h4>';
    foreach($something->data->observations[0]->$key as $item => $data){
      print_r(['item'=>$item,'data'=>$data]);
    }
    echo '<hr>';
  }

  print_r($something->data->observations[0]->$key);
  foreach($something->data->observations[0]->$key as $item => $data){
    if($item === '')
    print_r(['item'=>$item,'data'=>$data]);
  }
  print_r(['key'=>$key,'val'=>$val]);
  echo '<br>';
}
echo '<hr>';
print_r($something->data->observations[0]);
echo '<hr>';
print_r($something);
echo '<hr>';
exit;
```

Comment: Guest you have to decode it before making foreach? 

and the i get this error?

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Sorry, it's already on object. I've updated my answer. You might need to do one more step, if $item['location'] still throws errors. Can those location js-objects be strings? Or do you not control that?

Comment: & I was using array syntax instead of object. ( $parent['child'] instead of $parent->child )

Comment: As soon as you get the data from wow-auction (via file_get_contents, or curl) $foo = json_decode( file_get_contents(http://wow-auction.com/meraki/code.txt) ); do a print_r($foo);exit; then dig in to the data level by level. ( echo $foo->version, or echo $foo['version] )... then down to the next level until you get to the observations

Comment: you can use the gettype($var) function to tell you if a variable is object or array. objects use $key->val, arrays use $key['val']. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: It might take some fiddling, but if you take it step by step, going down one level in the data each time, outputting with print_r or var_dump... you'll get to the 'observations' array and from there you'll be able to iterate over the data.

Comment: What's the api url? I can try to get it for you - just upvote the hell out of my comments ;)

Comment: Good point below about the JSON, it might be invalid. Also, you might need to work with $json_object[0] instead of just $json_object. As soon as you get the json back from the api, (try this with live data, if you can) run: gettype($json) what's the result?

Comment: & you'll have to look in observations[0], it looks like that object is the first (0) index of the observations array.

Comment: Just updated my answer. corrected the json as well. here's what I see when I run it: http://dabzo.com/trythis.php

Comment: Try adding a second loop inside the foreach($something->data->observations[0] as $key => $val){ foreach($something->data->observations[0]->$key as $index => $data){ /* do something awesome */ } }. Good luck!

Comment: Updated my example again, hope that's enough to get you going! & here's the documentation for the foreach in php: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Those are just warnings, not errors that would prevent the code from running. I'm betting you'll need to wrap some of the output in if( isset($var) ) to avoid null values... Or try running it without the foreach($var as $key => $val) and use foreach( $var as $key ) instead. You'll need to re-work some of the output if you take away "=>$val" but you'll be able to achieve the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    // you have to use json_decode for sure

    $something = json_decode('{
    "version":"2.0","secret":"meraki","type":"DevicesSeen","data":{
        "apMac":"88:15:44:84:4c:90","apFloors":[],"apTags":["","recently-added",""]
        ,"observations":[{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":0.2907945825483442,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:24:43Z","ssid":null,"os":"Cisco/Linksys Router","clientMac":"94:9f:3e:06:c1:6c","seenEpoch":1495283083,"rssi":47,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
            "ipv4":"/10.226.198.65","location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":5.374873752610671,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:30Z","ssid":"DanfossConnect","os":"Slingbox","clientMac":"00:11:f6:f3:43:06","seenEpoch":1495283130,"rssi":46,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Asia Pacific Microsystems"},{
            "ipv4":"/172.16.0.25","location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":33.788906850703945,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:29Z","ssid":"Wireless WiFi","os":"HP Printer","clientMac":"c4:34:6b:08:dc:6d","seenEpoch":1495283129,"rssi":13,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hewlett-Packard"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":14.90854452921782,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:24:45Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"54:60:09:0e:08:d2","seenEpoch":1495283085,"rssi":31,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Google"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":0.287722117087862,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:54Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"94:9f:3e:06:c1:6d","seenEpoch":1495283154,"rssi":46,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":4.189862222398972,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:49Z","ssid":null,"os":"Cisco/Linksys Router","clientMac":"5c:aa:fd:40:29:78","seenEpoch":1495283149,"rssi":41,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":38.279358673491906,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:23:18Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"f4:42:8f:c3:84:8b","seenEpoch":1495282998,"rssi":16,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Samsung"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":39.49058481097055,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:28Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"a0:8c:fd:06:ec:17","seenEpoch":1495283128,"rssi":9,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hewlett-Packard"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":4.966494178173178,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:49Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"5c:aa:fd:40:29:79","seenEpoch":1495283149,"rssi":40,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Sonos"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46452206894476,"lng":9.39005605565066,"unc":28.907921961158962,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:22Z","ssid":null,"os":"iOS","clientMac":"b0:70:2d:84:38:cf","seenEpoch":1495283122,"rssi":13,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Apple"},{
            "ipv4":null,"location":{"lat":56.46451920053334,"lng":9.390050682697847,"unc":40.978157267912586,"x":[],"y":[]},"seenTime":"2017-05-20T12:25:34Z","ssid":null,"os":null,"clientMac":"60:6d:c7:85:91:17","seenEpoch":1495283134,"rssi":20,"ipv6":null,"manufacturer":"Hon Hai/Foxconn"}
        ]
    } 
    }',true);  
// first of all you miss an {
// use the second argument "true" to make it return an array



    foreach ( $something['data']['observations'] as $item ){

      $location_lng = $item['location']['lng'];
      $location_lat = $item['location']['lat'];
      echo $location_lng;
      echo '<hr>';
      echo $location_lat;
    // Everything is good :)
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: That doesnt work.


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: $something['data']['observations'][0] because the object is the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsonlint.com/ Your json code has syntax problem! one } was missing! Then go ahead with the other answers :)